# Workflow setting rich text field not preserving line breaks

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a workflow that I've created that will add a "comment" to a "comments" field saying when certain fields change. It is set up and working well, with one slight issue.

Instead of looking like this:

```
Field A updated: Value 1 -> Value 2
Field B updated: Value 3 -> Value 4
```

It looks like this:

```
Field A updated: Value 1 -> Value 2 Field B updated: Value 3 -> Value 4
```

I've double checked the workflow to make sure that the line breaks are in the value to set the comments field to.

I've also double checked that when populating that field on the InfoPath form, it will let me use multiple lines.

Any advice on how to get the workflow I've created to preserve line breaks?

Comment: Can you right click on the text and inspect to see what html is there? Are there any `\r` or `\n` characters between `Value 2` and `Field B`?

Comment: Yes, there are. That makes me even more confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When I was setting the variable value, I had to add a `<br>` on each line, instead of just doing a new line/line break/press enter.